# How do I write custom renderers with web.py

Tags: python, templates, render, web.py

Being new to python and web.py, I'm not sure if what I want is possible, but I'm trying to assign unique renderers for my templates so that my templates cant use a a specific file structure.

So I have:
code.py

```
Main = web.template.render('templates/', globals=common_globals)
Section1 = web.template.render('templates/Section1/', globals=common_globals)
```

And later when referencing these,

This works:

```
class index:
def GET(self):
    vPage = '0'
    vLevel = '0'
    vSection = '0'
    return Main.Layout(vPage, vLevel, vSection)
```

But this doesn't:

```
class Section1:
def GET(self):
    vPage = '0'
    vLevel = '1'
    vSection = '1'
    return Section1.Layout(vPage, vLevel, vSection)
```

Any advice to whether or not this is possible or how it works would be lovely.

Comment: Did you try it? It should work fine (I use different renders where my "pages" are different: one for rendering web pages, one for rendering HTML for PDF conversion, one for rendering HTML for emails.. That way I can provide the same parameters to each, yet generate different HTML   Note that the directory structure of your renderers has nothing to do with the directory structure of your web URLs.

Comment: @pbuck  It doesn't seem to work on mine, but I think I found a couple examples saying it should.  It technically works how I want it to work as a website: its just frustrating that something intuitive like that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have a file named "Layout.html" under both templates/ and templates/Section1/ directories?

Comment: Yes, the point of this test site was to mimic an existing site which has a structure where each "level" has its own layout, if only for potential control.

Comment: Guess I don't understand what isn't working!

Comment: Yeah, me either brother.  I'll have to circle back to it later: other fish to cook for the moment.

Comment: But thanks, at least I have a working version at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this unanswered in my questions.

I believe the issue was in the Layout.html, anything but all zeroes wasn't working because the variables were defaulting to zero.

Not sure what the exact version was when this was an issue, but working version of Layout.html is using something like:

```
$def with (vPage, vLevel, vDivision)
$:getNavigationHeader()
```

Univeersal.py having

```
def getNavigationHeader():
    vResult = ''
    
    vResult += '<h4>'
    vResult += 'Navigation'
    vResult += '</h4>'
    
    return vResult
```

All methods have a similar pattern.